# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 37.b

Tags: calculus

The instruction says:

> We define $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \infty$$ to mean that for all $N$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x$ if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $f(x) > N$
>   Prove that if $f(x) > \epsilon > 0$ for all $x$, and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = 0$, then:
>   $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{|g(x)|} = \infty$$

So with the definition it would be (I guess):

For all $N$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x$ if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $\frac{f(x)}{|g(x)|} > N$

What I know is:

Given $N>0$ we know $\frac{1}{N} > 0 $. Then I have to choose one $\delta > 0 $ such that $|g(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{N}$ for $0 < |x-a| < \delta$.

Or something like this, can someone please hep me find that $\delta$?

Comment: What I am thinking:
 $|\frac{1}{g(x)}| > \frac{N}{\epsilon}$.

As f(x) > $\epsilon$ then: $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| > \frac{N}{\epsilon} * \epsilon = N$

But I do not know if that proof is enough, I haven't found anything about $\delta$, can I assume that every $\delta > 0 $ works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $N>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies\bigl|g(x)\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon N$. Therefore$$|x-a|<\delta\implies\frac{f(x)}{\bigl|g(x)\bigr|}>\frac\varepsilon{\frac\varepsilon N}=N.$$

Comment: What if $g(x)=0$, for example? It seems to me that the problem statement should be extended with the assumption that $\exists\delta,\ \forall x,\ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies g(x)\neq 0$

Comment: @yellowcat Yes. I took it for granted that that was assumed.